# Unable to construct Context-free Grammar from Pushdown Automaton $a^n b^m$

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have a big problem with solving this $L = \{\,a^n b^m \mid 0 \le n \le m \le 2n\,\}$. I've try my best. I want to construct it. Please help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at 
$$\begin{align}S&\to \epsilon \mid aSB\\
B&\to b\mid bb\end{align} $$